# Changing different views in Xcode 6 os x application using Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, swift, xcode6

I'm checking out the new Xcode 6 Storyboards for os x application

I want to do the same like when doing push segue in iOS side.

But the new Xcode storyboards for os x application doesn't have the push segue.

[image]

So you can see there is no push. How to achive the same functionality?

Comment: you could try a custom segue.

Comment: thanks @carlodurso. Do you know an example for this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I've used a similar approach on my iPad app. It needs some tailoring for Cocoa:

```
-(void) perform {

    UIView *source = ((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController).view;
    UIView *destination = ((UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController).view;

    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    destination.center = CGPointMake(source.center.x + source.frame.size.width, destination.center.y);
    [window insertSubview:destination aboveSubview:source];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^{
                         destination.center = CGPointMake(source.center.x, destination.center.y);
                         source.center = CGPointMake(0- source.center.x, destination.center.y);}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [source removeFromSuperview];
                         window.rootViewController = self.destinationViewController;
                     }];

}
```

---

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I'll test and will let you know. Thanks carlodurso

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, a NSTabViewController might be appropriate. It lazy-loads view controllers and can transition using a slide animation.

Comment: Thanks Pierre Bernard, I'll give it a try